# Gradle properties chosen based on build version used

Tags: java, android, gradle

For an Android app, if my `build.gradle` has 2 schemes, prod and qa, how can I choose a `gradle_${chosen}.properties` based on the scheme? Ie in my build

```
prod {
  //use gradle_prod.properties
} 


qa { 
 //use gradle_qa.properties
}
```

If I try something like:

```
qa {
 processResources{

  // ...

  }

}
```

I get could not find method `processResources()`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.properties` file using something like:

```
def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = file('../fileName.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()){
     props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

     xxx = file(props['MY_KEY'])   
}
```

Instead if you want to use tasks defined in other `.gradle` files you can use in your file:

```
apply from: 'myFilename.gradle'
```